# WPF - binding to user control's Dependency property doesn't work without UpdateSourceTrigger

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties, propertychanged, updatesourcetrigger

I have a reusable UserControl for selecting language using combobox with DependencyProperty SelectedCulture. Then I have another control with list of users displayed in a DataGrid using UsersViewModel containing collection of UserViewModel. One column is a DataGridTemplateColumn containing the language select control. I bound the property SelectedCulture to property of the UserViewModel, but the binding is not updating the value of the UserViewModel unless UpdateSourceTrigger is set to PropertyChanged.

Why not? Shouldn't be the PropertyChanged default value?

LanguageSelectView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControls.LanguageSelectView" ... >
...
<ComboBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.AvailableCultures, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:LanguageSelectView}}}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCulture, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:LanguageSelectView}}}"
        >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    ...
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
</UserControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCultureProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedCulture), typeof(CultureInfo),
        typeof(LanguageSelectView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null) {BindsTwoWayByDefault = true, DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged});

public CultureInfo SelectedCulture
{
    get { return (CultureInfo) GetValue(SelectedCultureProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedCultureProperty, value); }
}

[Import]
public LanguageSelectViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
```

UsersView:

```
...
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="DataGrid" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_OnSelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{wpf:Localize PreferredLanguage}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <localization:LanguageSelectView SelectedCulture="{Binding SelectedCulture}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
...
```

UserViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    ...

    public CultureInfo SelectedCulture
    {
        get { <Getter> }
        set { <Setter> <-- It's not getting called! }
    }
}
```

When I update the binding with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, everything works as expected. I checked, whether the DependencyProperty is being updated by the language control by using PropertyChangedCallback and it was working without problems, so it looks like problem with binding on the side of the UsersView.

Thanks!

Comment: By default, it will only update when the control loses focus. By changing the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`, you are forcing it to update everytime the control is changed.

Comment: Even if the control loses focus, the value is not updated (I click on the combobox, switch value and click to some other control). And if you see the Dependency Property registration, I set the DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged which is being ignored.

Comment: Have you tried using `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead? That's what my choice would be in this situation.

Comment: I tried to add INotifyPropertyChanged to the LanguageSelectView and fire the event during change of the dependency property, but it's still not working :/

Comment: Naw, just skip the DP and implement INPC only and Raise the event in the setter.

Comment: Well, you cannot bind to non dependency properties. So that would defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: I've definitely bound directly to public variables in my ViewModel and used INPC, so sounds like the issue is elsewhere if that doesn't work